# Display list in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create histogram with the below values. This is the JSON format they are being parsed in, which I now want to visualise.

```
import json, requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = [[{"Name": "A"},{"Value":100}], [{"Name": "B"},{"Value":300}]]
```

Should I be converting to dictionary first? I want a histogram showing A:100, B:300.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take every pair and make a dictionary out of it. Then, make your histogram. Remember to use `xticklabels`.